# template many-to-many id django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-orm

how can i get an id of a many-to-many object?
i have three models, media, image and slideshow.
how can i get the id of a media through my slideshow object?

```
class Media(models.Model):
    CONTENT_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('photos', _('Photos')),
        ('videos', _('Videos')),
        ('audio', _('Audio')),
        ('Object360', _('360 Object')),
        ('Object3D', _('3D Object')),

    )


    source = models.FileField(upload_to='magazine')
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    content_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=CONTENT_TYPE_CHOICES)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Media')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Media')

class ImageComponent(BaseComponent):
    media = models.ForeignKey(Media)
    is_embed = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_slideshow =models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'Image Component'


class SlideshowComponent(BaseComponent):
    image = models.ManyToManyField(ImageComponent)
    is_autoplay = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_embed = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'Slideshow Component'
```

in my view.py i have: `slideshow = SlideshowComponent.objects.all()`
in template i try:

```
{% for slide in slideshow %}
{{ slide.image.media.id}}
```

but not works..

edit: how can aceess in view.py to the slideshow object through the media.id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, since `image` is a ManyToManyField it links to *many* images (it should really be called 'images'). So, you'll need to iterate through it:

```
{% for slide in slideshow %}
    {% for image in slide.image.all %}
    {{ image.media.id }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thanks, that is what im looking for.
if i sent by post an slideshow id, how in my view i can delete de medias of slideshow id i recived?